# DOCTYPE HTML not start my webpage on the localhost with console IE message

Tags: html, apache, internet-explorer, doctype

I´m tryng to run my webpage containing basics scripts `<?php..?>,<script>...</script>`, in LOCALHOST server, using Apache2triad.
It happens that script are running only to find `<!DOCTYPE...>` or without it in the IE console, the messages are sending like:

```
HTML1300:Navigation occured.
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
```

I already try to use declaration, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "Ok, running...."; ?>
```

or simply:

```
<html>
<body>
```

But the console error problem persist... Have you got some idea whats is happening with the server?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is IE compatibility** (it has nothing to do with Apache):
[How to use Compatibility View in Internet Explorer 9](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2536204)

**You can try to add X-UA-Compatible meta tag**:
(it also fixes some layout issues that occur in IE10):

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

**A quote from [Mozilla's Quirks Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla%27s_Quirks_Mode)**:

> The DOCTYPE shown in the example, , is the simplest
>   possible, and the one recommended by HTML5. Earlier versions of the
>   HTML standard recommended other variants, but all existing browsers
>   today will use full standards mode for this DOCTYPE, even the dated
>   Internet Explorer 6. There are no valid reasons to use a more
>   complicated DOCTYPE. If you do use another DOCTYPE, you may risk
>   choosing one, which triggers almost standards mode or quirks mode.

**How do you see which mode is used?**
In Internet Explorer, press F12, and look for Document Mode.